# Informações de JSP para outra JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Exemplo: Eu tenho uma JSP A, que tem algumas informações e um botão. Quando pressionar esse botão, a JSP A manda variaveis para B (como id, nome...). B usaria essas informações e atualizaria a página sem redirecionar. Há como fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

tudo bom ? Coloca um trecho do código que está tentando fazer para facilitar o apoio ao que precisa. Sem ter essa noção fica mais complicado ajudar.

Vamos ter algumas opções dependendo do que está utilizando. Se é só jsp com servlet, se usa o vraptor ou algum outro framework. Para cada situação você poderá ter uma opção diferente.

Mas levando em consideração somente a lógica que você precisa, vou considerar que está utilizando um método java que tenha o seguinte comportamento:

```
public void teuMetodo(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {
   //código aqui
   actionResponse.sendRedirect("paginaQueVcQuer.jsp");//Utilize o actionResponse para redirecionar após capturar os dados que precisa no seu form.
}
```

Abraço!

Answer (score -1):

Olá @Thiago R.

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso. Uma delas é pelo submit do form.

Outra seria utilizar o JSON. Você cria uma função Javascript que será disparado ao clicar nesse botão, então nessa função você irá passar os parâmetros que você quer por JSON indicando a próxima página. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function enviarDados() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/paginaJSP_B',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        data: { campo1: "abc", campo2: "XYZ" },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```